# whats about insurrance schemes according to islam? is it consider as interest or not?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, riba, hajj, insurance

MCB (Muslim Commercial Bank) Pakistan has started a scheme in which when one will go on hajj via there scheme he/she will be eligible for 4 months of free health (hadsaati) insurance,
my question is "is this interest or not"?
is this halal?
will it affect hajj or not?

Comment: waiting for any good response.

Comment: You need to add more detail. What is MCB? What type of insurance? Country? And most importantly, you need to rephrase your question so that it's on topic of the study of Islam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of scholars without any doubt agree that all tyep of insurance is haram. Every type of action, in which there is gambling or un-certainty involved, it to be avoided. 
and It is Best not to take any loan/insurance from Bank, as banks work only on interest and interest is haram.

Please follow this ruling: http://islamqa.info/en/8889

Comment: so what will be about hajj? if someone avail that offer and goes for hajj, his hajj will be accepted or not?

Comment: it is better to avoid it. or ask them Not to offer this to u or you dont want to take this offer. make sure its not given to you. or u dont pay a single penny to get enrolled for this insurance

Comment: its not me who is availing it but i have seen their posters i wanted to first confirm and then to stop those people to whome i know and they trying to avail it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but still want that what will be its affect on hajj?

Comment: obviously, when you will be enrolled for insurance, for first 4 months it will be free, but after that you/they MUST PAY to continue their insurance policy. so insurance is wrong now and after 4 months too. it is better to avoid it, to avoid inulding in haram act.

Comment: wait from your comment i have another question if one want to ony keep it for 4 months then?

Comment: still it would be haram (according to my opinion) as you Enrolled intentionally for a haram act of insurance. best is to avoid it